# Errors after uploading to Google playstore

Tags: android

My app runs perfectly when I run it using Android studio.

When I uploaded the app to the playstore, I started getting the following error:

```
12-19 13:42:14.971 18767-18767/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.djulie.acs.djulie_driver_new, PID: 18767
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.djulie.acs.djulie_driver_new/com.djulie.acs.djulie_driver_new.Menu.MainMenu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3255)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1796)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
    at android.support.v7.app.ae.b(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.p.setContentView(Unknown Source)
    at com.djulie.acs.djulie_driver_new.Menu.MainMenu.onCreate(Unknown Source)
```

I have add this code to the OnCreate event method, but it is still not working

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @Ajay..

i still get the same error

Comment: Read - [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` like this

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}

//then your onCreate method will be start
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by deleting ProGuard